# Jsoup - how to check if Element is of specific class?

Tags: java, jsoup

This is my Element code:

```
<tr class="footer">...</tr>
```

In the table there are also other rows with other classes and I process each of them. How can I know if this processed `tr` element has "footer" class?

Comment: If you want to pick only td with footer class and ignore other td you can `select` them using CSS query like `Elements footers = ancestorElementOrDocument.select("td.footer")`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already thought about it, but i also want to pick other td's. I would have to rewrite my whole code to use this code snippet. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Element#hasClass`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#hasClass-java.lang.String-) method.

```
if (element.hasClass("footer")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already searched a lot but didn't use it right. Sorry for the question but i thought it wasn't the right method. I am new to java ;)